# Is there any advanced compiler-compiler lexer/parser in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, lexer, compiler-compiler

I want to know Is there any compiler-compiler library that is written in C# or Not ?

I know Antlr & JavaCC but these library wrote in Java

Is there any library like antlr but in C# (or ported in C#) and open source or not ?

Can anybody introduce them ?

Comment: What target language are you trying to compile to? Why is it important it is written in C# - surely you just care that it is usable by C#? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This isn't exactly what you want, but it'll head you off in the right direction: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220042/Easily-Create-Your-Own-Parser. I wrote this a while ago in C#, but haven't updated it in a while.

Comment: I need a lexer/parser for generate any syntax like antlr but with antlr I need java and antlr.jar and I dont want this I want a lexer/parser pure in C#

Comment: ANTLR 4 C# port does not require Java - see [here](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs). Not even the compilation requires Java - it just speeds up the process.

Comment: @Widi I know about that Sam used IKVM for that so that is not Pure C# already

Comment: @Hamed The C# target for ANTLR 4 requires Java (or IKVM) for compiling applications. The resulting compiled C# applications will **not** require Java (or IKVM) to be installed. (source: [here](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/7cfe2ff7188e9c85e66f0f2b664840af64272268/Readme.md))

Comment: Wikipedia has an extensive list of Compiler-compilers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler  Your answer is probably in the wikipedial list of parser generators: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators

Comment: @IraBaxter a parser generator is a form of compiler-compiler. So ANTLR would fit this category. At least thats what your first link told me.

Comment: @Widi:  I agree, which I why I supplied the link to comparison of parser generators.  Sure enough, ANTLR is in that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Irony](https://irony.codeplex.com/). I've never used it myself though.

Answer (score 0):

The C# compiler is itself written in C#, and with Roslyn, this has been made open source.

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

There is also a C# port of JavaCC, however, it's no longer maintained.  The author switched to Irony instead.  If you're just looking for code for examples, it would do that.

https://github.com/deveel/csharpcc

Comment: Roslyn Can create any lexer and parser for me ? like antlr ? or this a lexer and parser for C# only ? I need to create any Lexer and Parser for any syntax

Comment: @Hamed - you didn't ask for a lexer written in C#, you asked if there were any compilers written in C#.  I don't really see the point in writing a new one when there already exist several out there, even if they're not in C#

Comment: I asked !!! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler , I asked Is there any compiler-compiler library in C# or NOT ? and I mentioned two examples Antlr and JavaCC

Comment: @Hamed - sorry, I read that as a compiler and/or compiler library.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: You answered the question, and then voted to close it as off topic?   Really??